# Why QTcpSocket doesn't write ? I need to flush it to make it send my data

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I read in the documentation that to send a packet with QTcpSocket I can just use the `write` method.
But when I do it, my server doesn't receive it. I need to call `flush` or `waitForByteWritten` to send it.

```
TCPClient::TCPClient(Client *babel , const std::string &hostname, unsigned short port, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), client(babel),  hostName(hostname), port(port), is_connected(false)
{
  this->tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);
  connect(this->tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(readMessage()));
  connect(this->tcpSocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(displayError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
  connect(this->tcpSocket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connectReady()));
  connect(this->tcpSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnectedReady()));

}

TCPClient::~TCPClient()
{

}

bool TCPClient::initiateService()
{
  this->tcpSocket->connectToHost(this->hostName.c_str(), this->port);
  this->tcpSocket->waitForConnected(5000);
}

void TCPClient::connectReady()
{
  this->is_connected = true;
}

void TCPClient::disconnectedReady()
{

}


bool TCPClient::sendBabelPacket(Protocol::BabelPacket &packet)
{
  if(this->tcpSocket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState && is_connected)
  {
    std::cout << "writing ... size : " << sizeof(Protocol::BabelPacket) + packet.dataLength<<std::endl;
    this->tcpSocket->write((const char *)&packet, sizeof(Protocol::BabelPacket) + packet.dataLength);
    //this->tcpSocket->flush();
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "socket close" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }
}


void TCPClient::shutDown()
{
  this->tcpSocket->abort();
}

void TCPClient::displayError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError)
{

}

void TCPClient::readMessage()
{
  char buffer[sizeof(Protocol::BabelPacket)];
  this->tcpSocket->read(buffer, sizeof(Protocol::BabelPacket));
}
```

When I call `write`, it returns the right amount of bytes.

I use this class in a GUI context, in the same thread.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation that you're referring to? Your summary sounds mistaken in several different ways (for example, packets are a TCP implementation thing and have nothing to do with this API) and I think I could clear up your misconceptions better if I could point out what the documentation you were looking at actually say. (Assuming it's correct, which .... who knows?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`QTcpSocket` is a buffered device, so data is not written directly, but into internal buffer. [Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html#details) states:

> Note: TCP sockets cannot be opened in QIODevice::Unbuffered mode.

Because of it you should call `flush` or `waitForBytesWritten` to be sure something is transferred.

There is the difference between them. `flush` writes as much as possible from the internal write buffer to the underlying network socket, *without blocking*. `waitForBytesWritten` *blocks* until at least one byte has been written on the socket and the `bytesWritten()` signal has been emitted.

Comment: Ok, I thought that it was because my write isn't working fine that readyRead is never emmited, but that doesn't seems to be the case ... Have you an idea why it is never emitted ?

Comment: @DimitriDanilov `readyRead()` emitted when new data arrived, are you sure your server sends response?

Comment: Yes I am sure, readyRead() is emmited only when I send my buffer with waitForBytesWritten(), but it is blocking ... When I flush the data arrived to my server, but I don't get his response because readyRead() isn't triggered. Maybe when I am in the GUI event loop it can't be triggered ?

Comment: @DimitriDanilov For GUI applications Qt signals rely's on the event-loop started during initialization of `QApplication`. `readyRead()` should be emitted if new data arrived and event-loop processes signals. Check that no long operations executed on your GUI thread and check that your `tcpSocket` is not `disconnected()` and there is no `error()`.

Comment: I start my application with app.exec(), that's all I do. My GUI is doing nothing when I should get a request, and I don't get any errors.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov Try to call `QApplication::processEvents()` after `flush()` and return from `sendBabelPacket` to see if some pending `readyRead()` event is not processed by event-loop.

Comment: I was just stupid, I instanciated my network before instanciating the QApplication... Thanks for your help anyway !